# How do I pass additional props along with react-router-dom props without getting TS error?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom, react-typescript

I am using typescript in react-router-dom history as below:

```
const Navbar: React.FC<RouteComponentProps> = ({ history }) => {}
```

but I want to pass another function as props as well, how do I do it with typescript?

```
const Navbar: React.FC<RouteComponentProps> = ({ history, onClick }) => {}
```

Comment: Hi, did try exactly what you did in the second code snippet and it failed? What error did you get, if it failed? Would you kindly add that error to the question?

Comment: You have to add the extra props in `React.FC<RouteComponentProps & { onClick: React.EventHandler<React.SyntheticEvent> }>`

Comment: what error you're getting, please put it in your question!